# for hierarchy grid, bind to local data, after edit in detail, will auto unexpand the detail

Tags: grid, edit, hierarchy

After I edit in the detal grid, the detail grid will unexpand.
I want it keep expand.
Thank you.
The following is my grid code:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    editable:true,
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "address" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
      {
          name: "Beverages",
          address: "street 1",
          products: [
            { name: "Tea", price: 20 },
            { name: "Coffee", price: 23 }
          ]
      },
      {
          name: "Food",
          address: "street 2",
          products: [
            { name: "Ham", price: 32 },
            { name: "Bread", price:34 }
          ]
      }
    ],
    detailInit: function (e) {
        $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: e.data.products,
            editable:true,
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: you should be more specific, what plugin are you using? What is your markup? Can you provide a fiddle with a working example of the problem?

Comment: This is the kendo-ui grid control, put the code in:
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
   // The code in the question
</script>
The do edit operation in the detail grid, if modified the content, leave the cell, the detail grid will collapse.

Answer (score 0):

The grid will collapse (unexpand) because it re-binds itself whenever a data item is updated. You will have to prevent the databinding.

```
detailInit: function (e) {
    var grid = this;
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: e.data.products,
        editable:true,
        save: function() {
          // Prevent the next data-binding
          grid.one("dataBinding", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a complete sample: http://dojo.telerik.com/uWuyI